# Can I restore apps from my SD card?

Tags: app2sd, restore, link2sd

I was a bit quick to switch phones, is it possible to restore the applications with their settings from the SD card (When they were installed on the card, ("regular" and Link2SD).

(I can of course get the apps from Google Play, but I would like the "old" settings to come back)

Comment: You could back them up on the old device using *Titanium Backup*, and use the very same app to restore them on the new device (Link2SD lets me assume both your devices are rooted).

Comment: I don't have it anymore (:- It was a discount for turning in my old phone :-)

Answer (score 2):

As you no longer have the original device, you've lost one option: Backing up those apps using [Titanium Backup ★ root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), sending those backups to the new device, and restoring them with the very same *Titanium Backup*.

If you didn't back up your apps before turning the device in, it's like asking: "I just burned those papers. Can I still get a copy of them?" At least the "regular" ones are gone that way, as [apps2sd](/questions/tagged/apps2sd) only moves a part of the app to your card. An essential part (including the app's data) is left in internal memory.

Still having your card, it *might* look a little different for the *Link2SD* part: Here you can at least pick the `.apk` files from your card, as they are still there. Unfortunately, the same cannot be said for their data: *Link2SD does not move application's private data files; it moves apk, dex (dalvik-cache) and lib files.* (from the [Link2SD app description on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD)).

If you additionally used [Root # All Data2SD card.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=rappsd.v1), it's again a completely different thing. In this case you should be able to re-install the app from the `.apk`, *Link2SD* it again, *Data2SD* it, shutdown the device, put the SDCard to your computer via a card reader, replace the data directories from the copy you've made of the old SDCard, unmount safely, put the card back to your Android device, and start it up.

Comment: and there are no settings regularly stored on the SD card?

Looks like I have to configure my Dropbox sync over again :)
(I actually had Titanium, but I used it mostly to move little used apps out)

Comment: Usually not: all app data (including settings) go to `/data/data/<package_name_of_the_app>`. Few apps offer (automatic or manual) backup of their settings to the sdcard. And even fewer store their data on sdcard by default.